# Bibliography on multiple pages

Tags: bibliographies, tufte

I am using Tufte Style Book Template and have a huge bibliography. For only bibliography page, I changed the page width to full by adding these two lines in the Bibliography environment:

```
\advance\rightmargin-\marginparwidth    
\advance\rightmargin-\marginparsep
```

It worked really well on the 1st page but on 2nd page of bibliography, again the bibliography page has introduced margin but I want to use full width for all pages of bibliography. Following figure explains it well

[image]

How can I fix it?

.bib file:

```
    @BOOK{Tufte2006,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Beautiful Evidence},
    year = {2006},
    publisher = {Graphics Press, {LLC}},
    month = {May},
    edition = {First},
    place = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-7-7}
}

@BOOK{Tufte2001,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {The Visual Display of Quantitative Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {2001},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-4-2}
}

@BOOK{Tufte1990,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{Tufte1997,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Visual Explanations},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1997},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-2-6}
}

@BOOK{abc1,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abc2,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abc3,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abc4,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abc5,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
    }

@Book{abc6,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abd1,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abd2,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abd3,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abd4,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abd5,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
    }

@Book{abd6,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

@BOOK{abe1,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abe2,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abe3,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abe4,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abe5,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@Book{abe6,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
@BOOK{abf1,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abf2,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abf3,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abf4,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abf5,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@Book{abf6,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
@BOOK{abg1,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abg2,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abg3,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abg4,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abg5,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@Book{abg6,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
@BOOK{abh1,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abh2,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abh3,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abh4,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abh5,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@Book{abh6,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
@BOOK{abi1,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abi2,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abi3,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abi4,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@BOOK{abi5,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}

@Book{abi6,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {Envisioning Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {1990},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-1-8}
}
```

MWE:

```
    \documentclass[symmetric, justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}

\hypersetup{colorlinks}% uncomment this line if you prefer colored hyperlinks (e.g., for onscreen viewing)

%%
% Book metadata
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}

% Inserts a blank page
\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}

\usepackage{units}

% Typesets the font size, leading, and measure in the form of 10/12x26 pc.
\newcommand{\measure}[3]{#1/#2$\times$\unit[#3]{pc}}


% Generates the index
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\cite{Tufte1997}
\cite{Tufte2000}
\cite{Tufte2001}
\cite{Tufte1990} \\

MWE \cite{abc1} \cite{abc2} \cite{abc3,abc4,abc5,abc6} \\
MWE \cite{abd1} \cite{abd2} \cite{abd3,abd4,abd5,abd6} \\
MWE \cite{abe1} \cite{abe2} \cite{abe3,abe4,abe5,abe6} \\
MWE \cite{abf1} \cite{abf2} \cite{abf3,abf4,abf5,abf6} \\
MWE \cite{abg1} \cite{abg2} \cite{abg3,abg4,abg5,abg6} \\
MWE \cite{abh1} \cite{abh2} \cite{abh3,abh4,abh5,abh6} \\
MWE \cite{abi1} \cite{abi2} \cite{abi3,abi4,abi5,abi6} \\

\begin{fullwidth}

\backmatter

\bibliography{sample-handout}

%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\printindex

\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A [minimale working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) would be real great to understand what's going on and provide a solution.

Comment: It's no good idea to manipulate the page parameters mid-document. And it would be a good idea if ... you would add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am sorry for not adding a working example as it will take alot of space. I have edited the tufte-common.def file that makes the bibliography page as full width, also it will required two pages of bibliography to add in MWE and the preamble code. So i shared my resultant picture to describe it a little bit more.

Comment: Tufte Style book has margins. I want to use fullwidth for Bibliogrphy part. As i mentioned earlier that I edited the Bibliography environment with two lines to use full width and it is working perfectly for the first page (page with green line in figure) of bibliography part but for next page of bibliography, it again shows margin (page with red line in figure).

Comment: Does your solution work every second page? That you haven't touched `\leftmargin` looks suspicious to me. We need a MWE to test. For a MWE you should just need to paste the code for one bibliography entry followed by a `\newpage` followed by the second entry, all inside a `hebibliography` environment, of course, and with the minimal preamble to get the code to compile. By definition, MWEs are *minimal* examples that exhibit the problem. It is very rare that a MWE needs to be huge.

Comment: Johannes_B, Christian and Andrew, I have tried to add an example. Hopefully I am now able to explain my problem better now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution and is suitable for "fullwidth" two sided, Tufte-Style book.

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, colback=white, colframe=white, check odd page, toggle left and right, grow to right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, toggle enlargement=evenpage]
%% In this part; paragraph/ TOC / LOF / LOT can be added to be used for fullwidth
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\printindex
%%
\end{tcolorbox}
```