# Multiple Page Index

Tags: indexing, tufte

I'm editing a family history, and the index is quite long. I'm using the tufte class, and have used the [full-width fix for a bibliography spanning several pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251698/bibliography-on-multiple-pages).

However, it's not working for my index, which is also several pages long. (I'm wondering if it has to do with the columns?)

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, colback=white, colframe=white, check odd page, toggle left and right, grow to right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, toggle enlargement=evenpage]
\printindex
\end{tcolorbox}
```

I've compiled several times, and here is what I get:

[image]

As you can see the entire page looks cut off entirely. How can I fix this?

(BTW, I'm more or less a n00b at this, so please let me know if I should provide more information.)

Comment: Maybe it works if you use the following in the preamble : \usepackage{imakeidx} \makeindex[columns=2] %

Comment: No dice. Still cut off, very similarly to the above figure.

Comment: I think you should hide one by one every option of tcolorbox (or 2/3 either) and see which is wrong

Comment: @PMC1234, none of them is wrong. I just think somehow it doesn't know how to break the box if there are more than one column inside of the box...

Comment: ... Do you really need tcolorbox then? Does it work without it? Otherwise what is the problem without tcolorbox?

Comment: @PMC1234, Without tcolorbox the tufte class can't handle fullwidth over multiple pages. See the link in my post for the explanation of that.

Comment: It would help to have a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: (I am on my phone so I can't use LaYeX for the moment sadly)... Have you also tried the geometry package then ? Use in preamble '\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} and at the page of the index \newgeometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,bottom=1cm,right=1cm}

Comment: A full example would be helpful!

Comment: @Andrew, will do. It'll take a bit for me to work on. Thanks for that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the reason that the index was printing improperly. In the preamble, setting the `symmetric` option under `\documentclass` was the problem. Removing this option also fixes [the problem of multiple page bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251698/bibliography-on-multiple-pages).

```
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,openright,justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
%...
\begin{document}
\input{main_content.tex}
%...
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Here is the first page of the index; all of the subsequent pages look fine as well.

[image: full-width index]